# Insert JSON data into radio input with javascript

Tags: javascript, sql, json

I have a DB, where a php post values with JSON to my app.
My wish is to fill the values into the inputs where they original was user generated.

I can use this command to fill text inputs:

```
document.getElementById("value1").value=item.value1;
```

But how do i return the value to radio input?

Answer (score 1):

Set the `checked` attribute like so:

```
document.getElementById('radioId').checked = 'checked';
```

Inversely, you can remove the attribute to *uncheck* it:

```
document.getElementById('radioId').removeAttribute('checked');
```

Write example:

```
<input id="maleRadioBox" type="radio" name="sex" value="male">Male<br>
<input id="femaleRadioBox" type="radio" name="sex" value="female" checked>Female</input>
[...]
if( values.maleChecked )
   document.getElementById('maleRadioBox').checked = 'checked';
else
   document.getElementById('maleRadioBox').removeAttribute('checked');
if( values.femaleChecked )
   document.getElementById('femaleRadioBox').checked = 'checked';
else
   document.getElementById('femaleRadioBox').removeAttribute('checked');
```

Read example:

```
<input id="maleRadioBox" type="radio" name="sex" value="male" checked>Male<br>
<input id="femaleRadioBox" type="radio" name="sex" value="female">Female</input>
[...]
if( document.getElementById('maleRadioBox').hasAttribute('checked') )
   values.maleChecked = 'checked';
// or maybe values.maleChecked = document.getElementById('maleRadioBox').hasAttribute('checked');
if( document.getElementById('femaleRadioBox').hasAttribute('checked') )
   values.femaleChecked = 'checked';
// or maybe values.femaleChecked = document.getElementById('femaleRadioBox').hasAttribute('checked');
```

You could always make a function to simplify it:

```
function updateRadioInput( id, checked ) {
  if( checked )
    document.getElementById( id ).checked = 'checked';
  else
    document.getElementById( id ).removeAttribute('checked');
}

updateRadioInput( 'maleChecked', values.isMaleChecked );
updateRadioInput( 'femaleChecked', values.isFemaleChecked );
// etc...
```

Comment: hmm .. where do i set the JSON value: item.value1 ?

Comment: I thought the question was how to set the radio input as checked/not-checked based on your JSON data. To set the JOSN data based on the checked state, maybe something like this `item.value1 = docuemnt.getElementById('radioId').hasAttribute('checked') ? "checked" : null;` would work?

Comment: you are right, it is to set checked/not-checked based on my json data. so i have a div around the radio inputs with id = radioId, and then it should work?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, but `radioId` was meant as a placeholder for the id of your radio input.

Comment: uh, im actually not working with placeholders, i probably should - how should i place placeholders on radio inputs? sorry for my newb-ness :)

Comment: Does the edit help? (oops, there were issues with the last edit, i just cleaned it up)